# how can I append querystring to object?

Tags: php, oop, api, zend-framework

Google has chanced some things with their calendar API, and now I need to fix some strange symbols that are adding themselves to text.  I found this thread which exactly describes the issue I'm dealing with:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=25ac3d762b235a51&hl=en

The solution is to append "&hl=en" or "?hl=en" to the end of my 'basic' URL feed.

I'm confunsed how to do that though, because I am retrieving the feed as an object with Zend_Gdata:

```
<?php
// load library
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

// create authenticated HTTP client for Calendar service
$gcal = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$user = "xxxxx";
$pass = "xxxxx";
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $gcal);
$gcal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

$query = $gcal->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser('xxxxx@group.calendar.google.com');
$secondary=true;
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setProjection('basic');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setSortOrder('ascending');
//$query->setFutureevents('true');

$startDate=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$endDate="2015-12-31";
$query->setStartMin($startDate);
$query->setStartMax($endDate);
$query->setMaxResults(30);
try {
  $feed = $gcal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getResponse();
}

?>
```

I tried to do this with no luck:

```
$query->setProjection('basic?hl=en');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I've not used any of this before so I apologize if this doesn't work :)

The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html) says that `getCalendarEventFeed()` can take a URL as the parameter.
So we can change this...

```
$feed = $gcal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
```

... to this in order to add the parameter to the query string:

```
$eventUrl = $query->getQueryUrl() . '?hl=en';
$feed = $gcal->getCalendarEventFeed($eventUrl);
```

Obviously, this is a simplified example - you should still perform the following two checks:

1. Make sure `$query` is an instance of `Zend_Gdata_Query` before calling `getQueryUrl()` on it.
2. Ensure that there are no other query parameters already added to `$eventUrl` so that we can use `&hl=en` rather than `?hl=en`. You could probably use [`Zend_Uri`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.uri.html) for this.